# MVC, Jquery mobile and the datepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Ok so im expanding my existing MVC4 app into a mobile app.

Totally new to jquery mobile and im having so many issues with this in MVC.
Layout pages (MVC) and jquery mobile are a nightmare to work with or is it just me?

So im simply trying to show jquery ui datepicker in my page, it does not show!
I have to do a reload of the page for it to show, why???

Ok Layout page

```
@{
    Layout = null;

}

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>



        </head>
        <body>
            @RenderBody();
        </body>

    </html>
```

and now the view

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AppLayout.Iphone.cshtml";

}


<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });

</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div data-role="page" id="pageAccount">
    <div data-role="content">

       <div id="datepicker"></div>
</div>

        </div>

}
```

Any ideas why the page shows, but no datepicker (I have to reload the page for it to show)?

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 0):

### Solution :

This should be changed:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageAccount', function(){       
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

To make a story short. jQuery Mobile should not be used with classic **`DOM`** ready **`jQuery`** functions. Instead **`jQuery Mobile`** is providing us with page events. If you want to find out more about jQuery mobile page events and how they work take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, to make it transparent it is my personal blog. Or you can take a look **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.

### Edit :

Here's a working example:

Change positions of

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

into:

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

**`jQuery Mobile`** should always load last when used with **`jQuery UI`**.

Also you have forgot **`jQuery UI`**  **`CSS`**, you will find datepicker without its **`CSS`** formatting.

Comment: Nope, just an empty screen

Comment: Take a look now at my answer example.

Comment: Still the same, it only works if i reload the page, are you using MVC?

Comment: MVC don't play any role here, you have a javascript error. Take a look at my example and use it to find your problem. If it is working in a simple example like mine it should also work for you.